# HQl query to get week of the year

Tags: hibernate, hql, date-formatting, week-number

I need to make the following MSSQLServer query which gets number of changes made in current weeek

```
select count(1) from Audit_tbl where DATEPART( wk, action_time)=DATEPART( wk,getdate())
```

I get strucked with the functionDATEPART( wk, action_time)=DATEPART( wk,getdate()) is there any equivalent in HQL.

Also is there a way to get date(2014-03-24) part from 2014-03-24 20:56:26.297 in HQL

**Update:**

```
select DATEADD(day,datediff(day,0,action_time),0) AS ActionDate,
count(1) as total 
from Server_tbl
where YEAR(action_time) = YEAR(getdate())
group by DATEADD(day,datediff(day,0,action_time),0)
```

it gives the records group by actiontime(stored in db as timestamp)

Comment: What is your goal ? There is no simple date function I think, but depending of what you want to do, there are different options.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a week() function in HQL. And you cannot mix HQL and SQL.

Therefore, you can either use an SQL query or switch to Criteria queries and implement your own `SQLCriterion` to produce the exact SQL fragment you want (see javadoc [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/SQLCriterion.html))

Update: another option I missed is the extract() function. 
First, you must configure your Hibernate to use `SqlServerDialect` (or one of its subclasses).
Then the extract function will be translated as `DATEPART` in SQL and the following clause should do the trick :

```
... where extract(wk from actionTimeProperty) = extract(wk from current_date())
```

Comment: any suggestion to get date part from 2014-03-24 20:56:26.297